# Convert a SQL BIT into JSON through to jQuery and finally display in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm working with checkboxes and JSON and I'm trying to find the cleanest way to set a checkbox on a JSON return.  The JSON pulls from a BIT field out of SQL, and the code below works but I don't really like it...

PHP:

```
$outputArray = array(
    'submissionaddress' => htmlentities($row['StateSubmissionAddress'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'),
    'isactive' => $row['IsActive']);
return json_encode($outputArray);
```

JSON:

```
{"submissionaddress":"Temp","isactive":"1"}
```

jQuery:

```
success: function(data) {
    var checked = (parseInt(data.isactive, 10) === 1) ? true : false;
    $('#submissionAddressCheckBox').attr('checked', checked);
}
```

Javascript didn't like `(data.isactive)` and that always returned false, so I parsed it to an int.  I assume that's because JSON returns `"isactive":"1"` and it's interpreted as a string.

What's the best way to interpret a BIT value into JSON, and than transfer that value into a checkbox in HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would have to change to an integer at all. Could you ask `data.isactive==='1'`?

Comment: Javascript is dynamically typed, it makes 0 difference if its a 'BIT' or string.  Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.  Just do data.isactive === '1'

Comment: data.isactive ==='1' will work fine, but why can't javascript interpret (data.isactive) as true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `string` to an `int` with `+` and then the `!!` converts to a boolean.

```
success: function(data) {
    var checked = !!+data.isactive;
    $('#submissionAddressCheckBox').attr('checked', checked);
}
```

Comment: I know data.isactive === '1' will work, but do you know why javascript can't interpret (data.isactive) as true or false?

Comment: Well when it comes over as json it is a string, since there is a value contained within that string it will equal 'true' . However i edited my post I forgot there is another way to do what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Does your Ajax request has dataType set to json? If not you should parse it.

Comment: Ajax request is set to json and that works fine, I'm just trying to find the best way to handle the boolean values, preferably without a string comparison.